# Simultaneous visits to website

Tags: php, mysql

Will there be any problem if my website is being visited by more then one person simultaneously...? If the answer is yes, can you say how can i overcome that?

Do I have to incorporate the session? Will that alone work? Please explain with a small example.

Comment: The main problem I can foresee is that they won't be able to understand a word you're saying.

Answer (score 4):

Going off the lack of information:

Your website will not have any problems if multiple people visit at the same time. More than likely, the software you are using is built specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There will generally be no problem. A normal PHP/Apache server setup is designed to handle multiple requests at once. Sessions are always on a per-client basis.

For more specific info, you would have to provide more information about your setup, but if you're just starting out building a web site, it is safe to say that you don't need to worry about this for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Session are not necessarly needed BUT you should really keep in mind that you data can be read and modified by multiple users in concurrency.
Look at [ACID definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) for the engineering part of it :)